# subdirectories of website.com always redirect to www.website.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'm using Amazon Web Services' Elastic Beanstalk for a website. I bought a custom domain and transferred the DNS settings to AWS following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/server/namecheap-domain-name-and-amazon-ec2/) tutorial.
After waiting I followed [this](http://www.objectliteral.com/custom-domain-elastic-beanstalk/) tutorial.

I set it so if I was to enter website.com it would redirect www.website.com. However if I was to enter website.com/login it would redirect to ww.website.com without the subdirectory.

What I would like is if someone was to type website.com/login they would get redirected to www.website.com/login.

The reason I would like to the 'www.' is for consistency and SEO. How can I do this using AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what your looking to do in terms of forcing a www. redirect can be done using mods to your htaccess file.

In your .htaccess document (FTP root directory), add the below code -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Replace example.com with your domain name and you should be good to go.